# What does "length of the last" means refering to shoe size?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I think the title speak for itself, google translator was not very helpful since it understands the word last like "last place"

This is the part of the text

> In France, Germany, and most other European countries, the traditional shoe size is the **length of the last**, measured in Paris points

Comment: Clearly, you need to look in a [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/last?q=last#last-3v), and not rely on Google Translate.

Comment: hmm. thanks! well I was trying to translate whole sentence directly to my language but it was nonsense. anyway **a shoemaker’s model for shaping or repairing a shoe or boot.** That is weird. Many shoemaker's can have different sized models but OK. I thought it is some unified unit for measuring.

Comment: The unified unit in which lasts are measured is called the ***Paris point***..

Comment: ahh, now I see, sorry, I was so focused on the "last" word that I was not thinking at all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the [last](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last) is the wooden (or other material) form used to form the shoe:

> A last is a mechanical form that has a shape similar to that of a
>   human foot. It is used by shoemakers and cordwainers in the
>   manufacture and repair of shoes. Lasts typically come in pairs, and
>   have been made from various materials, including hardwoods, cast iron,
>   and, high density plastics. [(Wikipedia "Last")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last)

and therefore the "length of the last" refers to the end-to-end length of that form.  Here's another reference using the wordk `last` in the same way, from the New Balance website:

> A shoe last is a 360 degree model of the foot used to create each
>   shoe's heel width, instep height, toe box width and toe box depth.
>   Though it's not the primary factor, in conjunction with length and
>   width, the shoe last helps our customers achieve the best possible
>   fit. [New Balance "Shoe Lasts"](http://www.newbalance.com/shoe-last-chart/shoe-last-chart,default,pg.html)

Answer (score 1):

"Shoe size in the United Kingdom (British size) is based on the length of the last, measured in barleycorn (1/3 inch) starting from the smallest practical size, which is size zero. It is not formally standardised."

It's a UK/European way of measuring the size of a shoe.

Please, do some research first!

Comment: Yes I was reading about the barleycorn at first (and I thought, seriously? barleycorns?) But I did not know what the last is. I just did not get it. It sounds to me like "last part of the foot" which is heel actually, but it was clarified to me in comments. Thanks everyone for explaining

Comment: Are you saying that British and European shoe sizes are the same?

Comment: @WS2: Paris points are 2/3 of a centimeter. Barleycorns are 1/3 of an inch. There are 1.27 Paris points in a barleycorn.

Comment: @Peter Shor I take size 10 shoes in Britain, which is size 11 US, but in Continental Europe it is 44.5. So how does that work in Paris points and barleycorns?

Comment: @WS2 Are _you_ saying that British shoe sizes and British shoe sizes are the same?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well they do vary a bit, but not much. My point is that if there are 1.27 Paris points in a barleycorn, a size 10 in Britain should be 12.7 in France, shouldn't it? But it is 44.5!

Comment: @WS2 I find it very risky buying shoes over the internet; shoe sizes seem as unreliable as the L's and XL's of shirts.

Comment: This answer does not address the point the OP was confused about, namely: *"What is a last?"*

Comment: @WS2: British shoe sizes start at size 0: the minimum possible length of a foot (at least, according to whoever thought up the scale). This corresponds to 31 in european sizes.

Comment: @PeterShor You can't actually buy a size 0, unless that is 13 in a childrens' size. Kids' sizes go up to 13, and then they are next into an adult size 1.

Comment: Peter, I just added an answer referencing what the technical term `last` means in the world of shoes, which I believe answers the OP's original question.  This one was new to me too!

Comment: Oh, dear, I just discovered that the reference to which Peter linked in his first comment contains the definition as well!